# Replacing if (Convert.ToString(rdr["Data"]) != bItems)

Tags: c#, sqlite

I want to replace if (Convert.ToString(rdr["Data"]) != bItems) with something that would check if data already exist in my database or not to make process faster as going in that loop taking too much time for bigger database. Plz HELP!

```
for (int p = 0; p < 256; p++) {
    bItems += "P" + buffer[p];                                   
}
        
using (SQLiteConnection con = new SQLiteConnection(databaseObject.myConnection)) {
    con.Open();
    SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand("select ID, Data from B where Data like 'P%'", con);
    var rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    while (rdr.Read()) {
        if (Convert.ToString(rdr["Data"]) != bItems) {
            SQLiteCommand cmd1 = new SQLiteCommand("INSERT INTO B ('Data') SELECT @Data  WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT ID, Data FROM B WHERE  Data = @Data)", con);                                                
            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Data", bItems);
            cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
        }
        else (Convert.ToString(rdr["Data"]) == bItems) {
            sItems = "B" + Convert.ToString(rdr["ID"]);
            rdr.Close();
            break;
        }
    }
}
bItems = "";
Console.WriteLine(sItems);
}
```

Comment: Take a moment to read through the [editing help](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help) in the help center. Formatting on Stack Overflow is different than on other sites. The better your post looks, the easier it is for others to read and understand it.

Comment: @gunr2171 - Please let me know which part of question ou were not able to understand.

Comment: Please read through the [editing help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) page to make the code you've posted more legible. You see how most of it is massively indented? In addition, it's best to make and post a [mre].

Comment: @gunr2171 I hope it looks better now

Comment: @gunr2171 Can you please help me with the issue

Comment: @dude, do you want to check if data exists in database before sending a query to database?

Comment: @Hasan Emrah Sungu - Yes. so that it does not compare with each and every entry....I think it would be faster

Comment: @dude, there is no way to know if data exists before sending a query. It looks like you are doing a simple select query so it shouldnt take so much time. Did you set your indexes correctly?

Comment: In the `else` case, uou call `(Convert.ToString(rdr["Data"])` twice. Consider pulling that into a temporary variable before the `if`. You might also want to lookup the column indexes for `"ID"` and `"Data"` so you look things up in the DataReader by ordinal rather than by string. Oh, and why `Convert.ToString`, why not just `ToString`

Comment: @Hasan Emrah Sungu - I misunderstood your question earlier....ofcourse does not want to know if data exists before sending quesry.....Let me try indexing....Thanks for your help

Comment: @dude, what happened after indexing?

Comment: @HasanEmrahSüngü - Thanks for following up. Indexing did bring it down to under 5 mins from 30+. However it is still too much for a 30 MB file. Trying iSR5's idea. however it is not working so far.

Comment: @Hasan Emrah Sungu - Is there anything else I can do to process it even faster ??

Comment: @dude, just by indexing you decreased more than 80% of processing time. I can not comment further without seeing /debugging your actual code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of reading each row and check the data against `bItems`. You may need to either query the table to see if there is any record matches `bItems`, if not then insert it. Or, you can simply insert the data if not exists (which what you did in the first condition.

To simplify your work, you can do this :

```
// insert the new item if not exists in the table 
// returns the item Id
private int InsertDataIfNotExists(string bItems)
{
    using (SQLiteConnection connection = new SQLiteConnection(databaseObject.myConnection)) 
    using(SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand("INSERT INTO B ('Data') SELECT @Data WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM B WHERE  Data = @Data);", con))
    {
        connection.Open();
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Data", bItems);

        // insert data if not exists
        command.ExecuteNonQuery(); 

        // get the data's Id
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT ID FROM B WHERE Data = @Data LIMIT 1;";
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Data", bItems);
        var result = cmd.ExecuteScalar()?.ToString();
        
        return int.TryParse(result, out int id) && id > 0 ? id : -1;
    }
}
```

with the above, you only insert the data if not exists, and then return the id.

usage :

```
var insertResultId = InsertDataIfNotExists(bItems);

if(insertResultId == -1)
{
    // handle exceptions 
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine(insertResultId);      
}
```

Comment: @iSR5- Thanks for your response. However, code above still enters data into database even if it exist in it already.

Comment: @dude then revise it to this `IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM B WHERE Data = @Data) INSERT INTO B ('Data') SELECT @Data;` check it out.

Comment: @iSR5- Sorry to reach out to you again . Program is now giving me following error 'SQL logic error near "IF": syntax error'

Comment: @dude ops, I just realized that you're using SQLite, it does not support `IF NOT EXISTS`. The `WHERE NOT EXISTS` should work just fine, how come it's inserting the value?  try the insert outside the code with a test value, see if it will insert it or not.

Comment: @iSR5- I am still getting the same error System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteException: 'SQL logic error near "WHERE": syntax error'

Comment: @dude  it's the same query that you have in your post, what is the difference ? please check the executed query in the profiler, to identify the query error.

Comment: It worked, thanks for your help. Is there anything else can be done to make it even more faster?? Program is still taking over 6 mins to process file of 27MB.

Comment: @dude as for the query part no, but for the file processing itself, yes. you need to mark this post as answered, then open a new post and include the file processing logic (where you read, write, file bytes) to see where we can optimize the code to improve the performance.